# Restarting a prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

Currently learning how to work prompts.  When the user inputs a false value into one of my prompts, it kills the script and displays a blank page. Instead of going blank, I want to program to restart the prompt to give let the user try again without having to refresh the page. Any tips?

Shorter version of the code:

```
var subjectGender="";  
var genderOK=true;  
var originalGendertag="male";  
var newGendertag="female";


subjectName=prompt("What is the subject's name?",subjectName);
subjectGender=prompt("Is "+subjectName+" male(M) or female(F)?","M or F");
if ((subjectGender!="M")&&(subjectGender!="F")){  
    alert("Must enter M or F");
    genderOK=false;
    originalGendertag="female";
    newGendertag="male";
}
if (genderOK==true){
    document.write(subjectName+" is "+originalGendertag+".")
}
```

Comment: Put the prompt in a function and call the function again to show the prompt again. [Learn more about functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html). Or use a loop.

Comment: I semi tried that earlier and couldn't get it to work, but I probably did something wrong. I'll keep trying that to see if I can get it to work

Comment: please post your code and what you have tried

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Add your code, or this question will be closed.

Comment: Got it with the function! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just have a recursive function call if the user does not enter the value that you expected.

```
// Call the function
showPrompt();

function showPrompt() {
  var age = prompt("Please enter your age: ");
  // The prompt will be shown until the user hits 24 in this case
  if (+age !== 24) {
    showPrompt();
  } else {
    console.log('Close my prompt !!');
  }
}
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hc80yhnp/)**